# how to fix my Caesar Cipher function and how the % loop over within the length?

Tags: python

```py
realText = input('please enter a string: ')
step = int(input('please enter step for shifting'))

def caesar_encrypt(realText, step):
    outText = []
    cryptText = []
    
    uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    for eachLetter in realText:
        if eachLetter in uppercase:
            index = uppercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % len(uppercase)
            cryptText.append(crypting)  #list of each crpting index
            newLetter = uppercase[crypting]
            outText.append(newLetter)
        elif eachLetter in lowercase:
            index = lowercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % len(lowercase)
            cryptText.append(crypting)
            newLetter = lowercase[crypting]
            outText.append(newLetter)
    print((' ').join(outText))
caesar_encrypt(realText, step)
```

**Input:**

```
BEWARE THE IDES OF MARCH 
step: 13
```

**Unexpected output:**

```
O R J N E R G U R V Q R F B S Z N E P U
```

**Expected output:**

```
ORJNER GUR VQRF BS ZNEPU
```

As my code is shown above, how can I fix this code to get my desired output? and I don't understand how the modulus operators are able to use to loop over the length of a sequence and isn't it for the reminder? can anyone explain more details about that? will be very appreciated.

Comment: on top of my head, the issue should be here: `print((' ').join(outText))`, check out the docs to be sure, but this joins each element of the array with a space as separator and prints it. You don't want that: you need to join the elements into words first, and that will need a logic of its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `else` case in your code and join finally list with `''` as shown below

```
realText = input('please enter a string: ')
step = int(input('please enter step for shifting'))

def caesar_encrypt(realText, step):
    outText = []
    cryptText = []
    
    uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    for eachLetter in realText:
        if eachLetter in uppercase:
            index = uppercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % len(uppercase)
            cryptText.append(crypting)  #list of each crpting index
            newLetter = uppercase[crypting]
            outText.append(newLetter)
        elif eachLetter in lowercase:
            index = lowercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % len(lowercase)
            cryptText.append(crypting)
            newLetter = lowercase[crypting]
            outText.append(newLetter)
        else:
            outText.append(eachLetter)
    print(''.join(outText))
caesar_encrypt(realText, step)
```

Comment: thanks! and can you also explain how the % work for looping over the length and it is supposed to calculate the reminder? i am super confusing about this.. pls help

Comment: It divides two numbers and returns the remainder. Here https://www.jquery-az.com/python-modulo/ you can see some examples related to that operator